# Finding Green's Functions with Unmixed Boundary Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$L= (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2})-k^2$ that satisfies (and this is where I lose it) $u(0)=u(1)$ and $u'(0)=u'(1)$

I'm having trouble figuring out a practice problem I am working on.
I need to find the Green's function. I tried setting the equations equal to each other like $u(0)-u(1)=0$ and $u'(0)-u'(1)=0$ but was unsure if that was a good way to go or even correct for that matter.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a Green's function should be independent of the boundary conditions.  You've essentially described a 1-D Helmholtz operator, whose Green's function is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Table_of_Green.27s_functions  The boundary conditions should only matter when you're trying to find a particular solution of the operator.

Comment: @nukeguy:  Green's functions are in fact dependent on boundary conditions.  This is easiest to see if you think about them as "the response of the system to an idealized impulse", i.e., a Dirac delta-function.  If you think of a wave on a string, a fixed end vs. free end result in Dirichlet vs. Neumann boundary conditions, and the Green's function will be different depending on whether your "idealized impulse" is reflected right-side-up or upside-down at the boundary.

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The Green's Function is defined as follows:

The Green's function $G(x,x')$ satisfies the ODE

$$\frac{d^2G(x,x')}{dx^2}+k^2G(x,x')=0 \tag 1$$

for $x\ne x'$.

In addition, $G(x,x')$ is continuous at $x'=x$ and $\frac{dG}{d}$ is discontinuous at $x'=x$ such that

$$\begin{align}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(G(x,x+\epsilon)-G(x,x-\epsilon)\right)&=0 \tag 2\\\\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac{dG(x,x+\epsilon)}{dx}-\frac{dG(x,x-\epsilon)}{dx}\right)&=-1\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Finally, $G$ satisfies the boundary conditions

$$G(0,x')=G(1,x') \tag 4$$

$$\left.\frac{dG(x,x')}{dx}\right|_{x=0}=\left.\frac{dG(x,x')}{dx}\right|_{x=1} \tag 5$$

Now, solving $(1)$, we find that

$$G(x,x')=
\begin{cases}
A\sin(kx)+B\cos(kx)&,x\le x' \tag 6\\\\
C\sin(k(1-x))+D\cos(k(1-x))&,x\ge x'
\end{cases}$$

Finally, to find the constants $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, simply apply the two continuity conditions $(2)$ and $(3)$ along with the two boundary conditions $(4)$ and $(5)$ to $(6)$.

This results in a linear system of $4$ equations with $4$ unknowns, the solution of which is left as an exercise for the reader.